# eth-brownie: Deployed contract returning as transaction receipt instead of the contract itself. I cannot grab the contract from the address or alias

Tags: deployment, transactions, contract, receipt, brownie

I deployed a token on the BSC network
[transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6NaY.png)

it saved the object as a transaction
[receipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjFsP.png)

it is not returning the contract object, as it shows in the [docs](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-contracts.html#deploying-contracts).

I also cannot grab the contract from the address. I have a mint function in the contract that I am trying to run. I cannot do this with just the transaction receipt can I?

When I tested on ganache test network, it returns a contract object. I was able to run the mint function just fine! but on the live network I am having some issues.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "required_confs" key to the tx data should solve this.

```
should_be_instance_of_contract = contract.deploy(
    {"from": account, 'required_confs': 3},
    publish_source=True
)
```

vs.

```
should_be_tx_receipt = contract.deploy(
    {"from": account},
    publish_source=True
)
```